# Plot straight line along y axes using 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

I am trying to plot a straight line on the 3D surface (x,y,z) along the base of this plot from (1,3,0) to (1,6,0). The straight line along the x plane is not plotting and I can't seem to figure out what my error is. I have found a few similar questions to this but couldn't find where my mistake is.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# points
z = np.repeat(0.1, 100) 
x = np.repeat(1.0, 100) 
y = np.linspace(start=3.0, stop=6.0, num=100) 

# set axes limits
ax.set_xlim(6,3)
ax.set_ylim(0,1.1)
ax.set_zlim(0,1.75)

# plot
ax.plot(x, y, z, c='red',label=r'straight line at $x=1.0$')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I am holding x and z fixed while changing the y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (likely accidentally) switched the x-axis and y-axis limits. Try this

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# points
z = np.repeat(0.1, 100) 
x = np.repeat(1.0, 100) 
y = np.linspace(start=3.0, stop=6.0, num=100) 

# set axes limits
ax.set_xlim(0,1.1)
ax.set_ylim(6,3)
ax.set_zlim(0,1.75)

# plot
ax.plot(x, y, z, c='red',label=r'straight line at $x=1.0$')
plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Thanks, I see what you did there, one also has to take the orientation into account.

Comment: Just FYI, the line was also present in your original graph, but wasn't in the field of view. When plotted with an interactive figure, I could rotate the plot and see the line off somewhere in the distance. It's a helpful troubleshooting trick you should keep in mind, especially for 3d plots.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and check that out.